# How to add thousand separators in a mixed string

Tags: c#, numbers, number-formatting, digit-separator

I have a mixed string with numbers and operations (only), like `"1234567.89+876-5432*10.1234"`.
And each time I click a number, it will add it to that string (so I need to keep it as only 1 string).

I'm trying to add thousand separators (comma).
so the results I'm trying to get is `"1,234,567.89+876-5,432*10.1234"`.

Note: It needs to be added automatically as the user typing. Please.

I tried to read about it all over the place, but couldn't figure how to achieve that.
Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: I think you're building a simple calculator application as a programming exercise? I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. But solving it the right way is a "Data Structures and Algorithms" topic.

Comment: Though I guess there is a short answer `decimal.Parse(string).ToString("#,#.#############################");`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you wanna add a number to the string , convert it into a string and put a comma at the end and then add it to the main string.

if you have a number like 20.

```
int numb = 20;
string convertedNumb = numb.toString()+",";
```

and then just add the convertedNumb to the main string

```
string newMainString = convertedNumb + mainString;
```

Then probably you need to put that in a event trigger for any key pressed.